# get row onclick table in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

how can I get the row I clicked from table ?

so that I can recover the data I want. the click is working

```
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="row">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" onclick="{!c.showRow }" >
                    <td data-label="OpportunityNumber__c" >
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.OpportunityNumber__c}">{!row.OpportunityNumber__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Date" > 
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.CreatedDate}">{!row.CreatedDate}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Nom Affaire" >  
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!row.Name}">{!row.Name}</div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
```

constorller js

```
showRow:function(component,event,helper){
  console.log("it's work");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr class="slds-hint-parent" data-myid="some data" onclick="{!c.showRow }" >
```

Then in JS:

```
showRow:function(component,event,helper){
  console.log("it's work ", event.currentTarget.dataset.myid);
}
```

Comment: i try like this myid="{!row.OpportunityNumber__c}" then in js event.currentTarget.myid .
I get undefined

Comment: its event.currentTarget.dataset.myid

Comment: it's work thank you